# How to achieve zero downtime deployment with database schema changes

Tags: sql-server-2005, web-applications, deployment, replication, downtime

I need to achieve zero downtime deployment for my e-commerce site while performing database schema changes. The database is sql server 2005. Can someone verify whether the following steps are feasible? Please provide your suggestions.

1. The principal database will serve the requests and changes will be replicated to mirror database.
2. Before deployment, stop replication process from principal to mirror.
3. Perform database schema changes to mirror.
4. For a short pause, make principal read-only.
5. Replicate changes from principal to mirror again.
6. Route the requests to mirror (Perform role switching)
7. Perform database schema changes to original principal (now mirror after the role switch).

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts about both the feasability and the usefulness of step 5 - if the principal is read-only *and* there's a role switch, why would you try replicating changes?

Comment: While database schema changes were being updated in mirror, principal would have some new data which need to be replicated to mirror. The principal is made read-only for a short while so that there are no new records in principal database when replication is being performed in step5.

Comment: I see. Then, you need to check if SQL Server supports replication between databases that have different schemas (I would be surprised if it did, but I might be wrong).

Comment: Found 2 references that replication is supported among databases with different schemas - Provided read-only on the subscriber is ok then an indexed view on the
publisher could be replicated using transactional replication(Ref:http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34233735/replication-of-tables-with-diffrent-schema.aspx). Alternatively stored procedure could be used(Ref: http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-replication/how-to-synchronize-dbs-having-different-schemas-68602.shtml)
one using stored procedure and

Comment: Ah, indexed views. Hadn't thought of that, but I can see why it would work. This would require you to add an additional step before step 2, which is to construct the indexed views (otherwise, it might not be ready in time when you wish to resume replication).